# Is it possible to subclass android.content.ClipData or ClipData.Item?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

Basically, I'd like to subclass `ClipData.Item` so that I can send data other than `CharSequence`, `Intent` or `URI` along with a `DragEvent`. The docs seem to suggest this is possible (see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.Item.html#toString) alongside the `toString()` method, which specifically mentions subclasses of `Item`), however everything I've tried hasn't worked despite neither `ClipData` nor `Item` being declared `final`.

The basic setup that I've got is an inner class extending `ClipData.Item` like so:

`TowerButton.java`

```
package com.conundrum.toweroffensenative.app;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Nums on 27/03/14.
 */
public class TowerButton extends View {
    private Paint mBackgroundPaint, mTowerPaint, mShadowPaint, mLabelPaint, mDisabledPaint;
    private List<Tower> mTowers;
    private Path mTowerPath;
    private DragShadowBuilder mDragShadowBuilder;

    private Rect r;

    public TowerButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, List<Tower> towers) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mTowers = towers;
        init();
    }

    // If I need a tower type that starts with 0 stock, add constructor which takes Paint/Path as args
    private void init() {
        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
        mBackgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        mTowerPaint = mTowers.get(0).getPaint();
        mTowerPath = mTowers.get(0).getPath();

        mShadowPaint = new Paint(mTowerPaint);
        mShadowPaint.setAlpha(150);

        mDisabledPaint = new Paint(mTowerPaint);
        mDisabledPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        mDisabledPaint.setAlpha(150);

        mLabelPaint = new Paint();
        mLabelPaint.setTextSize(28);
        mLabelPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mLabelPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mLabelPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        mDragShadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(this) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
                canvas.drawPath(mTowerPath, mShadowPaint);
            }
        };

        setTag(mTowers.get(0).getClass().getName() + "Button");

        r = new Rect();
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return String.valueOf(mTowers.size());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        Matrix pathMatrix = new Matrix();
        RectF pathBounds = new RectF();
        mTowerPath.computeBounds(pathBounds, false);
        pathMatrix.setScale(w / pathBounds.width(), h / pathBounds.height());
        mTowerPath.transform(pathMatrix);

        r.set(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(r, mBackgroundPaint);

        if (mTowers.size() > 0) {
            canvas.drawPath(mTowerPath, mTowerPaint);
            canvas.drawText(getQuantity(), getX() + (getWidth() / 2), getY() + (getHeight() / 2), mLabelPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawPath(mTowerPath, mDisabledPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && mTowers.size() > 0) {
            Tower dragTower = mTowers.get(0);
            TowerItem item = new TowerItem(dragTower);
            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(dragTower.getBuildRow(),
                    new String[]{ ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }, item);

            startDrag(dragData, mDragShadowBuilder, null, 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Tower giveTower() {
        // TODO: need checking to ensure size > 0?
        Tower tower = mTowers.remove(0);
        invalidate();
        return tower;
    }

    public void recycleTower(Tower tower) {
        mTowers.add(tower);
        invalidate();
    }

    public static class TowerItem extends ClipData.Item {
        final Tower mTower;

        public TowerItem(Tower tower) {
            super("");
            mTower = tower;
        }

        public Tower getTower() {
            return mTower;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence coerceToText(Context context) {
            if (mTower != null) {
                return mTower.getClass().getName();
            }
            return super.coerceToText(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the class which will accept the `DropEvent`:

`TowerView.java`

```
package com.conundrum.toweroffensenative.app;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

/**
 * Created by Nums on 24/03/14.
 */
public class TowerView extends View {
    private Paint mBasePaint, mHighlightPaint, mStunnedPaint, mSelectedPaint;

    private Tower mTower;
    private Path mTowerPath;
    private Paint mTowerPaint;

    private boolean highlighted;
    private boolean stunned;
    private boolean selected;

    private int mIndex;
    private List<TowerView> mNeighbours;

    private Rect r;

    private class mListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            for (TowerView tv : mNeighbours) {
                tv.highlighted ^= true;
                tv.invalidate();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            List<TowerView> myRow = ((TowerGrid) getParent()).getRow(mIndex % TowerGrid.ROWS);
            for (TowerView v : myRow) {
                v.stunned ^= true;
                v.invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
    GestureDetector mDetector = new GestureDetector(TowerView.this.getContext(), new mListener());

    Callable<Void> mStartRecycleCallable = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            startRecycle();
            return null;
        }
    };

    Callable<Void> mRecycleCallable = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            recycle();
            return null;
        }
    };

    public TowerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mIndex = -1;
        mNeighbours = new ArrayList<TowerView>();

        highlighted = false;
        stunned = false;
        selected = false;

        LinearGradient baseGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 25,
                new int[] {Color.LTGRAY, Color.DKGRAY}, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        LinearGradient highlightGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 25,
                new int[] {Color.YELLOW, Color.RED}, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        LinearGradient stunnedGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 25,
                new int[] {Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE}, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);

        mBasePaint = new Paint();
        mBasePaint.setShader(baseGradient);

        mHighlightPaint = new Paint();
        mHighlightPaint.setShader(highlightGradient);

        mStunnedPaint = new Paint();
        mStunnedPaint.setShader(stunnedGradient);

        mSelectedPaint = new Paint();
        mSelectedPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mSelectedPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mSelectedPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        r = new Rect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        r.set(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // Draw the tower base in one of three styles
        if (highlighted) {
            canvas.drawRect(r, mHighlightPaint);
        } else if (stunned) {
            canvas.drawRect(r, mStunnedPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawRect(r, mBasePaint);
        }

        if (mTower != null) {
            canvas.drawPath(mTowerPath, mTowerPaint);
        }

        if (selected) {
            canvas.drawRect(r, mSelectedPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean result = mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (!result) {
            // Custom gesture code
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean result = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDragEvent(DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // check if Tower can be built on this col - in case I allow that to differ per Tower
                if (mIndex / TowerGrid.ROWS == Integer.parseInt(event.getClipDescription().getLabel().toString())) {
                    selected = true;
                    invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                highlighted = true;
                invalidate();
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                highlighted = false;
                invalidate();
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                if (item instanceof TowerButton.TowerItem) {
                    Log.d("towerview", "SUCCESS!");
                }
                // Always returns false
                TowerButton.TowerItem tItem = (TowerButton.TowerItem) item; // exception
                Tower dragTower = item.getTower();
                setTower(dragTower);

                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                highlighted = false;
                selected = false;
                invalidate();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setTower(Tower tower) {
        if (mTower != null) {
            TowerButton button = (TowerButton) getRootView().findViewWithTag(mTower.getClass().getName() + "Button");
            button.recycleTower(mTower);
        }
        mTower = tower;
        mTowerPaint = tower.getPaint();
        mTowerPath = tower.getPath();

        Matrix pathMatrix = new Matrix();
        RectF pathBounds = new RectF();
        mTowerPath.computeBounds(pathBounds, false);
        pathMatrix.setScale(getWidth() / pathBounds.width(), getHeight() / pathBounds.height());
        mTowerPath.transform(pathMatrix);
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean advance(int distance) {
        if (!stunned) {
            // first account for the new view being added
            setTranslationX(getTranslationX() - distance);
            // then animate right over 1000 ms
            ViewPropertyAnimator animator = animate().translationXBy(distance).setDuration(1000);
            addCompatibilityAnimationCallback(animator, mStartRecycleCallable).start();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void startRecycle() {
        if (mIndex / TowerGrid.ROWS == TowerGrid.COLS - 1) {
            ViewPropertyAnimator animator = animate().translationXBy(getWidth() / -2).scaleX(0).setDuration(1000);
            addCompatibilityAnimationCallback(animator, mRecycleCallable).start();
        }
    }

    private void recycle() {
        if (mTower != null) {
            TowerButton button = (TowerButton) getRootView().findViewWithTag(mTower.getClass().getName() + "Button");
            button.recycleTower(mTower);
        }
        ((ViewGroup) getParent()).removeView(this);
    }

    public void updateNeighbours() {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
        mIndex = parent.indexOfChild(this);
        mNeighbours.clear();
        if (mIndex >= TowerGrid.ROWS) {
            mNeighbours.add((TowerView) parent.getChildAt(mIndex - TowerGrid.ROWS));
        }
        if (mIndex < TowerGrid.ROWS * (TowerGrid.COLS - 2)) {
            mNeighbours.add((TowerView) parent.getChildAt(mIndex + TowerGrid.ROWS));
        }
        if (mIndex % TowerGrid.ROWS != 0) {
            mNeighbours.add((TowerView) parent.getChildAt(mIndex - 1));
        }
        if (mIndex % TowerGrid.ROWS != TowerGrid.ROWS - 1) {
            mNeighbours.add((TowerView) parent.getChildAt(mIndex + 1));
        }
    }

    private ViewPropertyAnimator addCompatibilityAnimationCallback(ViewPropertyAnimator animator, final Callable<Void> callbackFunc) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            animator.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    try {
                        callbackFunc.call();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            animator.withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        callbackFunc.call();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return animator;
    }
}
```

There are no compile-time errors. However, when attempting to perform the cast at runtime, I get the exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.ClipData$Item cannot be cast to com.conundrum.toweroffensenative.app.TowerButton$TowerItem`

Similarly, code like `item instanceof TowerButton.TowerItem` returns false, even though `TowerItem` is obviously extending `ClipData.Item`.

Is there something I'm missing that prevents these classes from being subclassed? Or am I doing something wrong? I know I could use a `ContentProvider` and `URI`s to transfer more complex information, but that seems like overkill when the data being transferred never has to be made available outside this application.

**EDIT**

I've also tried making a subclass of `ClipData` with it's own `Item` inner class, so that I can override `getItem()` to return a `TowerItem` - but then I need to cast a `ClipData` to a `TowerClipData`, which fails with the same error.

**EDIT 3**

Included the entirety of both relevant files.

Answer (score 0):

`TowerItem` is descended from `ClipData.Item`, therefore a `TowerItem` is a `ClipData.Item` but the reverse is not always true. A `ClipData.Item` can be a `TowerItem` but it isn't necessarily.

You avoid the compiler error by explicitly casting `ClipData.Item` to `TowerItem`: `(TowerItem)ClipData.Item`. But you cannot avoid runtime error.

The right usage of `instanceOf` should be in this way:

```
if(event.getClipData().getItemAt(0) instanceOf TowerButton.TowerItem) {
    TowerButton.TowerItem item = (TowerButton.TowerItem) event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but with that code, `event.getClipData().getItemAt(0) instanceof TowerButton.TowerItem` never returns true. That makes sense because the `ClipData` is being specified by me in `onTouchEvent`. I've edited my answer to include that code, so you can see that `getItemAt(0)` should always be an instance of my class.

Comment: You must put TowerItem into ClipData to be able to get and successfully cast it to TowerItem later.

Comment: I have - look at the code after **EDIT 2**. I instantiate a `TowerItem` and pass it to the constructor of `ClipData`

Comment: Can you show the whole part of the relevant code? I wonder how and where where you declare your classes.

Comment: Ok, I've got the entirety of both files in there now. TowerView.java is quite long - I thought about cutting some out but figured I'd better leave it all just in case I take out something relevant.

Comment: Did you try to return false in onTouchEvent method of the TowerButton class? It is important whether the touch event is consumed or not in that level. Maybe you could not successfully send the startDrag because you consumed the touch there.

Comment: No, I know the DragEvents are coming through successfully (the DragShadow renders, all the other views react correctly to ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED and ACTION_DRAG_EXITED, etc) and besides, the exception is happening within the ACTION_DROP section of the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem, and I've been going over the system code for this. Basically, the ClipData is a Parcelable, so I think a subclass of ClipData.Item which doesn't have a sensible subclass of ClipData that recognises your custom ClipData.Item is going to get converted to a Charsequence and then come back as a basic text ClipData.Item. Otherwise, you need to create a ContentProvider for the URI format, which, for this use case, a ui in a single app, is overkill and possibly wrong.
My hack for this was eventually to pass an identifying tag in the ClipData as text, and make the drag initiating view (passed in the event data via the state) responsible for turning this into an object. Not entirely clean but not totally ugly.